# GIMP logs me out

Tags: gimp

Never seen an error like this. I am using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. With gimp 2.1.0. I open an image in gimp, a basic little png and the screen goes black and I'm reset to outside my login page. I log back in and it's like I restarted the computer. There are no previous programs running. What could possibly be causing this?

Comment: How did you install `gimp` (https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/gimp or other?)?   If GNOME crashes (because of an extension intended for another version of GNOME or other reason), the user is logged out and forced to start another 'new' session by logging in, but I can't see how GIMP is involved, other than maybe your issue relates to GTK2 configuration used by GIMP that causes GNOME to crash.  I'd maybe look at your GTK2 settings/configs.

Comment: It's not a *logout*. It's a *desktop crash*. Look for the .crash file in /var/crash, which will explain in highly technical terms exactly what crashed and why. Check http://errors.ubuntu.com to see exactly how many similar reports have been received, and to check the progress on the corresponding bug report.

Comment: Gimp 2.1.0? Really ? Or is 2.10.x?

Comment: Same issue here. Gimp 2.10.20 and 2.10.18